# Business Info Rich Snippet

Tags: rich-snippets

If you search Google for "company information" you'll see that a lot of websites have a new snippet showing information about the business in grey after the breadcrumb trail. What does a business do to get that snippet?

[image]

Comment: That apparently is from wikipedia.

Comment: What happens when you click at the triangle icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For that you will need to have a Wikipedia business page.**

You can verify this by clicking on the gray triangle on google's search result page.

You can follow this link to create a Wikipedia business page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Article_wizard

**Guidelines:**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Article_wizard/Company_notability

In order to be included in Wikipedia, the company must be:

**1 -** the subject of multiple non-trivial published works whose source is independent of the company itself, OR

**2 -** listed on ranking indices of important companies produced by well-known and independent publications, OR

**3 -** used to calculate stock market indices. Being used to calculate an index that simply comprises the entire market is excluded.

If you are writing about a product or service of a company, that product or service must:

**1 -** have been the subject of multiple non-trivial published works whose source is independent of the company offering the product or service, OR

**2 -** be so well-known that its trademark has suffered from genericization.

**Conflict of interest/advertising**

**If you are closely associated with the company you want to write about, you have a conflict of interest** and will find it very difficult to write a good, neutral encyclopedia article. You will probably find it very difficult to write an article which will not look like advertising to other editors – and using Wikipedia for advertising has been against official policy for a very long time. To this end, if your article submission reads like an advertisement or does not meet the notability guidelines outlined above, it will most likely be deleted very quickly. The best advice here may be to do nothing: if your company is notable, someone else will write about it sooner or later. In the mean time, you could look for another topic to write about from the list at Wikipedia:Requested articles.

Answer (score 0):

This only appears to be rolled out on Google.com currently but Google detect if the company has a Wikipedia page and then shows a link with a snippet in a dropdown against results from those domains in their search results as @guisasso rightly points out the comments.