# Rich Text under Google Search Results

Tags: seo, google-search

I have few company profiles listed in a webpage. I want to make the webpages be listed in Google Search Results when a user searches for those profiles on Google. I also want to make the Google Search Results look like the one shown for Wikipedia. In the text below the search results one can see additional `Key` `Value` pairs.

In the below example fields like Owner, Founders etc.,

[image]

What should I do to achieve this?

I am currently able to see the results on Google Search, but the rich text (I do not know what it is called) doesn't appear below the results.

There are no errors shown on Google Search Console. However there are few minor warnings on Rich Results Test.

Such as `Missing field "tel" optional`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is called the "business info rich snippet."  Does this answer your question about how to get it? [Business Info Rich Snippet](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59549/business-info-rich-snippet)